# /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, awk, process, xargs, arguments

I am trying to run the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
filename=${file%%.*}
line1=$(sed -n 1~2p ${file})
seqs=$(grep -v '^>' ${file})
pos=$(echo "${line1}" | awk -F"[__]" 'NF>2{print $2}')

( 
    awk -v str="${seqs}" -v str2="${pos}" -v str3="${line1}" -v name=${filename} -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            n = split(str, a, sep)
            m = split(str2, b, sep)
            k = split(str3, c, sep)
            for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {o=10;d[$i]=b[i]-o;s[$i]=d[i]>0?d[i]:1; print c[i] "\n" substr(a[i],d[$i],2*o+(d[$i]<0?d[$i]:1)) > name"_flanks.fasta"}
        }
    '
)
```

however I am getting:

```
$ ./test.sh myfile.fasta
./test.sh: line 10: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long
```

Slap on the wrist for not using version control, but this was working in a previous version of my code. what seems to be the problem?

**edit:** have noticed that if I pipe "head ${file} |" into the sed and grep commands then this runs fine, but doing "cat ${file} |" re-produces the original error. could it really be a file size limitation? do I have to split the computation up into smaller file chunks?

output of `"$seqs$` is around 6,000 of these elements

```
MEDEAVLDRGASFLKHVCDEEEVEGHHTIYIGVHVPKSYRRRRRHKRKTGHKEKKEKERISENYSDKSDIENADESSSSILKPLISPAAERIRFILGEEDDSPAPPQLFTELDELLAVDGQEMEWKETARWIKFEEKVEQGGERWSKPHVATLSLHSLFELRTCMEKGSIMLDREASSLPQLVEMIVDHQIETGLLKPELKDKVTYTLLRKHRHQTKKSNLRSLADIGKTVSSASRMFTNPDNGSPAMTHRNLTSSSLNDISDKPEKDQLKNKFMKKLPRDAEASNVLVGEVDFLDTPFIAFVRLQQAVMLGALTEVPVPTRFLFILLGPKGKAKSYHEIGRAIATLMSDEVFHDIAYKAKDRHDLIAGIDEFLDEVIVLPPGEWDPAIRIEPPKSLPSSDKRKNMYSGGENVQMNGDTPHDGGHGGGGHGDCEELQRTGRFCGGLIKDIKRKAPFFASDFYDALNIQALSAILFIYLATVTNAITFGGLLGDATDNMQGVLESFLGTAVSGAIFCLFAGQPLTILSSTGPVLVFERLLFNFSKDNNFDYLEFRLWIGLWSAFLCLILVATDASFLVQYFTRFTEEGFSSLISFIFIYDAFKKMIKLADYYPINSNFKVGYNTLFSCTCVPPDPANISISNDTTLAPEYLPTMSSTDMYHNTTFDWAFLSKKECSKYGGNLVGNNCNFVPDITLMSFILFLGTYTSSMALKKFKTSPYFPTTARKLISDFAIILSILIFCVIDALVGVDTPKLIVPSEFKPTSPNRGWFVPPFGENPWWVCLAAAIPALLVTILIFMDQQITAVIVNRKEHKLKKGAGYHLDLFWVAILMVICSLMALPWYVAATVISIAHIDSLKMETETSAPGEQPKFLGVREQRVTGTLVFILTGLSVFMAPILKFIPMPVLYGVFLYMGVASLNGVQFMDRLKLLLMPLKHQPDFIYLRHVPLRRVHLFTFLQVLCLALLWILKSTVAAIIFPVMILALVAVRKGMDYLFSQHDLSFLDDVIPEKDKKKKEDEKKKKKKKGSLDSDNDDSDCPYSEKVPSIKIPMDIMEQQPFLSDSKPSDRERSPTFLERHTSC
```

The file contains many repeats of data like:

```
>Q9UM01_334_L_R
MVDSTEYEVASQPEVETSPLGDGASPGPEQVKLKKEISLLNGVCLIVGNMIGSGIFVSPKGVLIYSASFGLSLVIWAVGGLFSVFGALCYAELGTTIKKSGASYAYILEAFGGFLAFIRLWTSLLIIEPTSQAIIAITFANYMVQPLFPSCFAPYAASRLLAAACICLLTFINCAYVKWGTLVQDIFTYAKVLALIAVIVAGIVRLGQGASTHFENSFEGSSFAVGDIALALYSALFSYSGWDTLNYVTEEIKNPERNLPLSIGISMPIVTIIYILTNVAYYTVLDMRDILASDAVAVTFADQIFGIFNWIIPLSVALSCFGGLNASIVAASRLFFVGSREGHLPDAICMIHVERFTPVPSLLFNGIMALIYLCVEDIFQLINYYSFSYWFFVGLSIVGQLYLRWKEPDRPRPLKLSVFFPIVFCLCTIFLVAVPLYSDTINSLIGIAIALSGLPFYFLIIRVPEHKRPLYLRRIVGSATRYLQVLCMSVAAEMDLEDGGEMPKQRDPKSN
```

I want to read in the header (beginning with ">"), strip out the position number (334) and then with line 2 being the "sequence" I want to:

go to position `pos[i]` in `seqs[i]` and choose a substring of `seqs[i]` that is up to 10 positions either side of `pos[i]`. for example if `pos[i] = 15` I would return:

```
EYEVASQPEVETSPLGDGAS
```

I can do this when not using the entire file, however it appears that reading everything directly into awk would make the program more efficient than loading everything via shell variables.

Comment: The contents of `seqs` could be too large to pass on the command line (but could probably be passed to awk using a pipe). What is the output of `grep -v '^>' ${file}|wc -c` ?

Comment: you can pass the filename to awk, and read if from within awk to value awk's vars, instead of passing the values via shell variables. less size limitations that way.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - have included output of seqs

Comment: @Olivier Dulac - but would it still be possible to process using the sed and grep commands after reading the variables directly into awk?

Comment: @brucezepplin the idea would be to do it all from within awk (which can neatly emulate sed and grep). the only caveat would be if you need the external (= shell level) variables later, in which case you should continue as you are trying to do. where is the xargs, by the way?

Comment: @Olivier Dulac - if I put 'xargs' right before 'awk' I get "/usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long"

Comment: @brucezepplin : then $ line1 is too big. you can add a "-n 10" arg to xargs, so it breaks the input in 10 arguments chunk, and execute awk ... with these 10 args at the end. But i believe here xargs is not what you want : it changes completely the awk behaviour: instead of feeding awk's stdin, xargs will put the incoming stdin as arguments at the end of the awk command line ! please describe what you try to achieve

Comment: @Olivier Dulac yes it seems I'm going to have to figure out how to do this directly with awk, rather than through shell variables. I have updated the problem statement at the bottom of the question by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not do it just with `awk` only as offered by [@Olivier Dulac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27616/olivier-dulac):

```
awk '/^>/{split($0,N,"_");n=N[2];print;next}{print substr($0,n-10,20)}' file > file_flanks.fasta
```

same:

```
awk -F'_' '/^>/{n=$2;print;next}{print substr($0,n-10,20)}' file > file_flanks.fasta
```

Or without array:

```
awk '/^>/{print;sub("[^_]*_","");n=$0+0;next}{print substr($0,n-10,20)}' file > file_flanks.fasta
```

Comment: have been trying for the last hour! and you have just done it for me!